# How to update next data in mysql

Tags: mysql

create table mpr (
name nvarchar(50),
value nvarchar(50)
);
insert mpr
select 'Name','Ravi' Union all
select 'Gender','M' Union all
select 'Salary','38162' Union all
select 'Name','Sundar' Union all
select 'Gender','M' Union all
select 'Salary','34932' Union all
select 'Name','Jayesh' Union all
select 'Gender','M' Union all
select 'Salary','37224' Union all
select 'Name','Murali' Union all
select 'Gender','M' Union all
select 'Salary','43482' Union all
select 'Name','Priya' Union all
select 'Gender','F' Union all
select 'Salary','44831' Union all
select 'Name','Sandhya' Union all
select 'Gender','F' Union all
select 'Salary','26694' Union all
select 'Name','Karthik' Union all
select 'Gender','M' Union all
select 'Salary','36336' Union all
select 'Name','Premna' Union all
select 'Gender','F' Union all
select 'Salary','33432';
select * from mpr
I want output as metioned below
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3amD.png

```
select
case when name = 'Name' then value end as 'Name',

case when name = 'Gender' then value end as 'Gender',

case when name = 'Salary' then value end as 'Salary'

from mpr
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your table is lacking a primary key column which uniquely addresses each person.  Please add it.

Answer (score 0):

Your table is missing a primary key column which uniquely identifies each user.  Assuming that such an `id` column exist, we can try a pivot query here:

```sql
SELECT id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'Name'   THEN value END) AS name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'Gender' THEN value END) AS gender,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'Salary' THEN value END) AS salary
FROM mpr
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: without ID column I can use pivot function but I don't want to use pivot function. Is there any option to get the o/p as I mentioned in the screenshot??

Comment: @Manoj *without ID column I can use pivot function* You cannot. Nothing provides the rows processing order to be the same like these rows creation/insertion order which may result in data shuffle. The data which provides the relation (this row value is joined to those row value and not to any other row) must exist in the table.